# ns-3 logging - no logs on output

Tags: c++, linux, logging, ns-3

I'm trying to create new ns-3 module but somehow logs are not showing on output. I thought that it's problem with my code, so I copied first.cc and third.cc examples to the scratch dir and after running them, there was no logs too. I also tried to run them with an environment variable NS_LOG set to "*", but the output was same. When I try to print some text with std::clog or std::cout it is working but NS3 log macros are not (even NS_LOG_UNCOND).

I'm using NS version 3.31 and same problem is on Debian GNU/Linux 10 and also on Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I fix that?

Thanks, Filip

[image: output from commands]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using the optimized build. According to the [Logging documentation of v3.31](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.31/manual/html/logging.html),

> Logging statements are not compiled into optimized builds of ns-3. To use logging, one must build the (default) debug build of ns-3.

This is also the case for [the latest development version](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/logging.html) of ns-3. To switch to the debug build, run

```
./waf configure --build-profile=debug --out=build/debug
```

to set the build profile, followed by `./waf` to build. You can find more about the build profile in [the tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.31/tutorial/html/getting-started.html#building-with-waf).

Comment: Thank you, I was building it with optimized profile (simulator instalation tutorial said to do so). Debug profile fixed the issue.